# Different behaviour of sql command inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird2.5

Source table TEST (excerpt). The value in parentheses determines date type:

```
ID (integer)  |   SAMPLES (double precision)   | NSAMPLES (double precision)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
575            10.000000                        10.000000
```

Problematic SQL command is this:

```
insert into TEST
select * from TEST where ID=575;
```

If I execute this command from command line of open-source tool FlameRobin

[image]

the updated table looks like this

```
ID (integer)  |   SAMPLES (double precision)   |  NSAMPLES (double precision)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
575            10.000000                          10.000000
810            10.000000                          10.000000
```

If i run the same command from stored procedure (either from FlameRobin or my own application using BDE (Borland Database Engine) components) the result is this

```
ID (integer)  |   SAMPLES (double precision)   | NSAMPLES (double precision)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
575            10.000000                         10.000000
810            10.000000                         10.000000
811            10.000000                         NULL
```

What's intriguing both columns SAMPLES and NSAMPLES have same date type, same source value (= 10.000000) and both are nullable. Why copy command called from stored procedure don't copy value of NSAMPLES column? Instead of this it insert NULL value into the new record.

**Added 16.11.2012**

Maybe some hints can be found in following screenshots from db administrative tool FlameRobin. They contains full definition of stored procedure INSERT_TEST and table TEST.

[image]

[image]

Why is NSAMPLES column missing in fields list???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the different treatment of the IDENTITY column by the two environments.

Instead, do this:

```
 Insert into TEST(SAMPLES, NSAMPLES)
 Select SAMPLES, NSAMPLES 
 from TEST where ID = 575
```

I.e. if you explicitly name all your columns the problem will go away. This is generally a good idea anyway.

Comment: @truthseeker Yes the ID column must be an IDENTITY column. That's why in the inserted row the ID column gets a new value instead of 575 which is the value from the select statement.

Comment: Yes but question was about SAMPLES and NSAMPLES columns, not ID column. SAMPLES and NSAMPLES don't have IDENTITY property set.

Comment: @truthseeker, IDENTITY columns cannot be inserted into. This fact causes them to be treated differently when you do insert without a list of columns, which is causing your column lists not to match up as you expect. **Have you tried the solution I suggest?**